# set Position in matlab results in unexpected position

Tags: matlab, subplot

I have the following matlab code snippet that generates two subplots aside each other.

```
h = figure;
sp1 = subplot(1,2,1); hold on;
plot(xenDates, yXenDates, '.', 'color', cmap(1,:));
plot(xenPatchDates, yXenPatchDates, '.', 'color', cmap(2,:));
xlabel('Time in Months');
ylabel('Cumulative Number');
legend('Vulnerabilities','Patches','Location','northoutside');
sp1Pos = get(sp1, 'Position');
sp2 = subplot(1,2,2); hold on;
sp2Pos = get(sp2, 'Position');
plot(kvmDates, yKvmDates, '.', 'color', cmap(1,:), 'Markersize', 10);
plot(kvmPatchDates, yKvmPatchDates, '.', 'color', cmap(2,:));
xlabel('Time in Months');
ylabel('Cumulative Number');
set(sp2, 'Position', [sp2Pos(1) sp1Pos(2) sp2Pos(3) sp1Pos(4)]);
```

Since the legend is on top of the first subplot, i want to manually resize the second subplot so both have the same size. So i get the Position values and set them for subplot2 in the last line. Strangely, however, the subplot is shifted downwards a little so that the x-axis are not aligned.

This also occurs when i call

```
pos = get(sp2, 'Position');
set(sp2, pos(1) pos(2) pos(3) pos(4));
```

in direct succession.

Am i doing something wrong or is this a known issue?

***Update:***

Neither adding the drawnow; nor changing units to pixels changed anything. Attached an image that shows the issue.

[image: Misaligned x axis]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on R2014b, the subplots only get misaligned when I resize the figure... Did you try changing the `Units` property to `pixels`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you mention, the axes are aligned perfectly on my screen. I run 2012a. How about inserting a `drawnow` call before getting the positions of `sp1` and `sp2` axes?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: Ah sorry. Forgot to mention. It is R2013a. For now i "fixed" it by moving the right subplot up by 0.013 and reducing vertical size by the same value.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem in Matlab 2013a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I was able to reproduce your issue, it only happenes for very small figure sizes. Instead of resizing the second plot, draw a invisible legend on the right side. It will take exactly the same space the first legent takes:

```
h2=legend('Vulnerabilities','Patches','Location','northoutside');
set(h2,'visible','off')
```

And remove the last line from your code.

Comment: While i already worked around the issue due to the need to resize both subplots for printing anyways this did in fact solve the initial issue. Thanks very much! Noted for the next time!